# Can we downvote "down-vote" and "up-vote" in the Help Center?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammatical-correction

## [tl;dr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tl;dr#Phrase):

The terms "down-vote" and "up-vote" don't read as naturally as "downvote" and "upvote" respectively – the hyphenated versions are also used far less frequently.

**Can we eliminate the usage of "down-vote" and "up-vote" in the FAQ? <s>and rename the [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) and [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) tags?</s>**

<sup>(the tags have now been renamed to [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes) and [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes) — I've removed references to it from the title accordingly.)</sup>

---

## The current situation:

- The ["Vote Down" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) page in the Help Center uses "down-votes", "down-vote", and "down-voting" twice, but "downvotes" **five** times:

  > [image]
- (This was fixed by edits to the [excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23169), to the [wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23168), and by the [renaming of the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/383061/1364007) to [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes)) <strike>The [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/downvotes/info) for the [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) tag uses all hyphens:</strike>

  > [image]
- (This was fixed by edits to the [excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23171), to the [wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23170), and by the [renaming of the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/383061/1364007) to [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes).) <strike>The [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/up-votes/info) for the [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) tag uses a mix:</strike>

  > [image]
- Searches for ["downvote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22downvote%22+created%3A2019), ["upvote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22upvote%22+created%3A2019), ["down-vote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down-vote%22+created%3A2019), and ["up-vote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22up-vote%22+created%3A2019) filtered by the creation date on Meta Stack Overflow show the common usage is unhyphenated:

  [image: MSO Posts by year and year - unhyphenated wins.]

  [image: MSO Stacked posts by term - unhyphenated wins.]

  The same pattern is seen on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) too:

  [image: MSE Posts by year and year - unhyphenated wins.]

  [image: MSE Stacked posts by term - unhyphenated wins.]

---

## Justification:

I've done some research, and the following all point towards using "downvote" and "upvote" - both as the verb:

> I downvoted because your answer burnt my house down.

and as the noun:

> My downvote will not be retracted until I get my unicorn back.

Download/upload are linguistically similar words - most of us wouldn't dream of putting a hyphen in, e.g.:

> I'll down-load that file when I get home to my ISDN connection.

or:

> My up-load is a dossier of pluralisation problems.

so I've included them in my searches.

- [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) has entries for [downvote](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/downvote) and [upvote](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upvote), [download](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/download), and [upload](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upload) but searches for the hyphenated words point to the non-hyphenated words.
- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) has entries for ["vote {} up or down"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vote-sth-up-or-down), [download](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/download), and [upload](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upload) but nothing for "downvote", "upvote", "down-vote", or "down-vote".
- [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/) has entries for [downvote](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/downvote), [upvote](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upvote), [download](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/download), and [upload](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upload). A search for "down-vote" redirects to [vote down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vote-down); searches for the other words hyphenated don't give relevant results.
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) do not have pages for upvote/downvote (hyphenated or otherwise) but do have [download](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/download) and [upload](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upload). Searches for "down-load" and "up-load" redirect to the unhyphenated versions.
- [The accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20465/109567) to [*“Upvote” vs. “up vote” vs. “up-vote”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20457/109567) by [Karl](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6858/karl) (whose profile says that they are an "[EFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language) Teacher and Teacher Trainer") on the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) says:

  > Within the nomenclature of this site, upvote seems to be the accepted term.
- The ["Vote Up" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page in the Help Center uses neither "up-vote", "down-vote", nor any variant — but does use "upvote" twice, "upvotes" three times, and "upvoted" once.
- We have the [tactical-downvoting](/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting) and [downvote-reason](/questions/tagged/downvote-reason) tags whose excerpt and wikis use the non-hyphenated versions exclusively.
- [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/) and [Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/) (the founders of Stack Overflow) use "downvote" and "upvote" rather than "down-vote" or "up-vote", e.g. [JA-1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/), [JA-2](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/), [JS-1](https://twitter.com/spolsky/statuses/27244187286), [JS-2](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/13/gamification/).
- The Oxford Dictionaries page for [Hyphen (-)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen) says (emphasis mine):

  > **Hyphens joining prefixes to other words**
  >
  > Hyphens **can** be used to join a [prefix](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/prefixes-and-suffixes#prefixes) to another word, especially if the prefix ends in a vowel and the other word also begins with one (e.g. *pre-eminent* or *co-own*). **This use is less common than it used to be, though, and one-word forms are becoming more usual** (e.g. prearrange or cooperate).

---

## What I'd like to happen:

Ideally:

- (This has been fixed by tag renames - see above.) <strike>Questions with [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) and [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) would be retagged to [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes) and [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes) which don't exist (yet)</strike>.
- (This has been fixed by the creation of tag synonyms - see above.) <strike>[down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) and [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) become tag synonyms for [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes) and [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes)</strike>.
- (This has been fixed by edits - see above.) <strike>The tag excerpts and wikis for the new tags would be modified to use "downvote" and "upvote" (and variants like "upvoted", "downvotes") exclusively.</strike>
- The Help Center pages are modified to use the unhyphenated words.
- Everybody stops using "down-vote" and "up-vote" and variants in favour of "downvote" and "upvote". (I accept this is probably wishful thinking.)

Comment: Help! Rogue hyphens!

Comment: Ok, that's one up-vote (oh crap!) for "OMG this is a lot of work for a hyphen!" :)

Comment: I... had some free time. :)

Comment: isn't unhyphenated the informal language and the hyphen version only used for the formal acts?

Comment: @ocæon - I've done some more research and found no evidence to support the formal/informal usage - but have updated my answer with a quote on the declining use of hyphenated words .

Comment: I'm all for uniformity. Still... I kind of prefer the hyphenated versions. If you write it as upvote and downvote, they're really entities on their own and in that state carry the usual positive and negative connotations that we so desperately want to get rid of. But in fact they're both one and the same - "votes", and one happens to go up and one happens to go down. up-vote and down-vote just perfectly reflect that. IMO: keep it formal.

Comment: I don't see how hyphenating helps get rid of the positive/negative connotation of up(-)vote and down(-)vote.

Comment: Agreed - if you wanted to keep it formal for whatever reason you could say "vote down" or variants - the ["Vote Down" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) page uses "voting down" and "vote down" in addition to "downvote(s)". The hypenated versions don't appear to be recognised by dictionaries, so favouring them in formal use would be weird.

Comment: the growing familiarity of a previously hyphenated word https://www.jhsph.edu/news/style_manual/h.html#hyphenation , and a general shift away from including them http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7004661.stm .. both were quick to find. this appears to leave the most formal usages as the last to go. i feel the last bastion of hope for these hyphens is the ease of translation.

Comment: @ocæon - (1/2) In the cases of "downvote" and "upvote", the dictionaries (the four that I looked at, anyway) either don't recognise any variants, or only have the non-hyphenated versions: this isn't a previously hyphenated word losing the hyphen (as far as I can tell, anyway).

Comment: @ocæon (2/2) Style guides have contributed to this - for instance "The Elements of Style" advises "*Do not use a hyphen between words that can better be written as one word: water-fowl, waterfowl. Common sense will aid you in the decision, but a dictionary is more reliable. The steady evolution of the language seems to favor union: two words eventually become one, usually after a period of hyphenation.*". In this case I used a dictionary and found no hyphenated versions.

Comment: You will also have to get them to change the spell-checker in the comment editor, since it flags "downvoted" as misspelled, while "down-voted" is ok.

Comment: Ah, the evolution of language, how wonderful and inevitable.

Comment: That's your browser's spelling checker, not the site, @Mark. The website has no spelling checker.

Comment: @CodyGray: See, there's another thing to go on my list of "What I hate about web browsers!"

Comment: Plus one for using time wisely in one of those I-had-the-time-so-I-did-some-research kind of situations.

Comment: This is a mighty compelling argument for me to stop writing them as "down vote" and "up vote".

Comment: wow ~ similar analysis on meta.stackexchange.com http://i.imgur.com/Pax1Mkc.png and english.stackexchange.com http://i.imgur.com/gLJPlL8.png .. so i now concur completely! up voted!

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Good... Goood! Let the HATE flow through you.

Comment: My gut feeling is that more time went into *this* question than into some of the "data science" blog posts about the last developer survey...

Comment: *"I... had some free time. :)"* - Clearly, something should be done about *that*.    Next thing you will be using [Green Ink](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Green_ink) :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The superfluous hyphens have been excised. Feel free to upvote this answer (or downvote, if you must).

Comment: Aha! I have upvoted your answer accordingly.

Comment: No, the super-fluous hy-phens have been ex-cised.

Comment: There are still inconsistencies; for example [the badge requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) still have “up vote” and “down vote”, with a _space_.